# WinForms multi-threaded databinding scenario, best practice?

Tags: winforms, multithreading, data-binding

I'm currently designing/reworking the databinding part of an application that makes heavy use of winforms databinding and updates coming from a background thread (once a second on > 100 records).

Let's assume the application is a stock trading application, where a background thread monitors for data changes and putting them onto the data objects. These objects are stored in a `BindingList<>` and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to propagate the changes via databinding to the winforms controls.
Additionally the data objects are currently marshalling the changes via `WinformsSynchronizationContext.Send` to the UI thread.
The user is able to enter some of the values in the UI, which means that some values can be changed from both sides. And the user values shouldn't be overritten by updates.

So there are several question coming to my mind:

- Is there a general design-guildline how to do that (background updates in databinding)?
- When and how to marshal on the UI thread?
- What is the best way of the background thread to interact with
  binding/data objects?
- Which classes/Interfaces should be used? (BindingSource, ...)
- ...

The UI doesn't really know that there is a background thread, that updates the control, and as of my understanding in databinding scenarios the UI shouldn't know where the data is coming from... You can think of the background thread as something that pushes data to the UI, so I'm not sure if the backgroundworker is the option I'm searching for.

Sometimes you want to get some UI response during an operation in the data-/business object (e.g. setting the background during recalculations). Raising a propertychanged on a status property which is bound to the background isn't enough, as the control get's repainted after the calculation has finished? My idea would be to hook on the propertychanged event and call .update() on the control... 
Any other ideas about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a hard problem since most “solutions” lead to lots of custom code and lots of calls to `BeginInvoke()` or `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` (which itself is just a thin wrapper over `BeginInvoke`).

In the past, I've also found that you soon wish to delay sending your `INotifyPropertyChanged` events until the data is stable.  The code that handles one propriety-changed event often needs to read other proprieties.  You also often have a control that needs to redraw itself whenever the state of one of many properties changes, and you don’t wan the control to redraw itself too often.

Firstly, each custom WinForms control should read all data it needs to paint itself in the `PropertyChanged` event handler, so it does not need to lock any data objects when it was a `WM_PAINT` (`OnPaint`) message.  The control should not immediately repaint itself when it gets new data; instead, it should call `Control.Invalidate()`.  Windows will combine the `WM_PAINT` messages into as few requests as possible and only send them when the UI thread has nothing else to do.  This minimizes the number of redraws and the time the data objects are locked.  (Standard controls mostly do this with data binding anyway)

The data objects need to record what has changed as the changes are made, then once a set of changes has been completed, “kick” the UI thread into calling the `SendChangeEvents` method that then calls the `PropertyChanged` event handler (on the UI thread) for all properties that have changed.  While the `SendChangeEvents()` method is running, the data objects must be locked to stop the background thread(s) from updating them.

The UI thread can be “kicked” with a call to `BeginInvoke` whenever a set of update have bean read from the database.  Often it is better to have the UI thread poll using a timer, as Windows only sends the `WM_TIMER` message when the UI message queue is empty, hence leading to the UI feeling more responsive.

Also consider not using data binding at all, and having the UI ask each data object “what has changed” each time the timer fires.  Databinding always looks nice, but can quickly become part of the problem, rather then part of the solution.

As locking/unlock of the data-objects is a pain and may not allow the updates to be read from the database fast enough, you may wish to pass the UI thread a (virtual) copy of the data objects.  Having the data object be persistent/immutable so that any changes to the data object return a new data object rather than changing the current data object can enable this.

Persistent objects sound very slow, but need not be, see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx) and [that](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Immutability/default.aspx?p=2) for some pointers.  Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263585/immutable-object-pattern-in-c-what-do-you-think) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303426/efficient-persistent-data-structures-for-relational-database) on Stack Overflow.

Also have a look at [retlang - *Message-based concurrency in .NET*](http://code.google.com/p/retlang/). Its message batching may be useful.

(For WPF, I would have a View-Model that sets in the UI thread that was then updated in ‘batches’ from the multi-threaded model by the background thread.    However, WPF is a lot better at combining data binding events then WinForms.)

Answer (score 2):

There is an [MSDN article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150114082421/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188732.aspx) specific on that topic. But be prepared to look at VB.NET. ;)

Additionally maybe you could use [System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), instead of a generic second thread, since it nicely formalize the kind of interaction with the spawned background thread you are describing. The example given in the MSDN library is pretty decent, so go look at it for a hint on how to use it.

Edit:
Please note: No marshalling is required if you use the ProgressChanged event to communicate back to the UI thread. The background thread calls ReportProgress whenever it has the need to communicate with the UI. Since it is possible to attach any object to that event there is no reason to do manual marshalling. The progress is communicated via another async operation - so there is no need to worry about neither how fast the UI can handle the progress events nor if the background thread gets interruped by waiting for the event to finish.

If you prove that the background thread is raising the progress changed event way too fast then you might want to look at [Pull vs. Push models for UI updates](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/02/16/pull-vs.-push-models-for-ui-updates.aspx) an excellent article by Ayende.

Comment: System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker,may be part of the solution, however the hard problem is how to keep the data updates fast without looking out the UI thread.  Doing the above without having every other line of code having to think about locking or cross thread calls.

Comment: If you look at the Backgroundworker there is not much difference to spawning a thread and marshal with WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext the BW does the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes all the books show threaded structures and invokes etc. Which is perfectly correct etc, but it can be a pain to code, and often hard to organise so you can make decent tests for it

A UI only needs to be refreshed so many times a second, so performance is never an issue, and polling will work fine

I like to use a object graph that is being continuously updated by a pool of background threads. They check for actual changes in data values and when they notice an actual change they update a version counter on the root of the object graph (or on each main item whatever makes more sense) and updates the values

Then your foreground process can have a timer (same as UI thread by default) to fire once a second or so and check the version counter, and if it changes, locks it (to stop partial updates) and then refreshes the display

This simple technique totally isolates the UI thread from the background threads

Answer (score 1):

I just fought a similar situation - badkground thread updating the UI via BeginInvokes. The background has a delay of 10ms on every loop, but down the road I ran into problems where the UI updates which sometimes get fired every time on that loop, can't keep up with teh freq of updates, and the app effectively stops working (not sure what happens- blew a stack?).

I wound up adding a flag in the object passed over the invoke, which was just a ready flag. I'd set this to false before calling the invoke, and then the bg thread would do no more ui updates until this flag is toggled back to true. The UI thread would do it's screen updates etc, and then set this var to true.

This allowed the bg thread to keep crunching, but allowed the ui to shut off the flow until it was ready for more.

Comment: the only part im unsure of with this, is why the flag is allowed to be accessible form both threads. but it just seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new UserControl, add your control and format it (maybe dock = fill) and add a property. 
now configure the property to invoke the usercontrol and update your element, each time you change the property form any thread you want!

thats my solution:

```
    private long value;
    public long Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;

            UpdateTextBox();
        }
    }

    private delegate void Delegate();
    private void UpdateTextBox()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Delegate(UpdateTextBox), new object[] {});
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = this.value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

on my form i bind my view

```
viewTx.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", ptx.CounterTX, "ReturnValue"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that I solved in [Update Controls](http://codeplex.com/updatecontrols). I bring this up not to suggest you rewrite your code, but to give you some source to look at for ideas.

The technique that I used in WPF was to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to notify the foreground thread of a change. You can do the same thing in Winforms with Control.BeginInvoke. Unfortunately, you have to pass a reference to a Form object into your data object.

Once you do, you can pass an Action into BeginInvoke that fires PropertyChanged. For example:

```
_form.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName))) );
```

You will need to lock the properties in your data object to make them thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but I thought I'd give options to others. It seems once you start doing async programming and Windows Forms databinding you end up with problems updating Bindingsource datasource or updating lists bound to windows forms control. I am going to try using Jeffrey Richters AsyncEnumerator class from his powerthreading tools on wintellect.

Reason:
1. His AsyncEnumerator class automatically marshals background threads to UI threads so you can update controls as you would doing Synchronous code.
2. AsyncEnumerator simplifies Async programming. It does this automatically, so you write your code in a Synchronous fashion, but the code is still running in an asynchronous fashion.

Jeffrey Richter has a video on Channel 9 MSDN, that explains AsyncEnumerator.

Wish me luck.

-R

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but I believe this is still a valid question.

I would advise you to avoid using data binding at all and use `Observable` objects instead.

The reason is, data binding looks cool and when implemented the code looks good, but data binding miserably fails when there is lot os asynchronous UI update or multi-threading as in your case.

I have personally experienced this problem with asynchronous and Databinding in prod, we even didn't detect it in testing, when users started using all different scenarios things started to break down.